# Why is this node script raising a TypeError?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cmd, cron

I wrote a node script that deletes old email invitations from the database.  Eventually this script will run daily as a cron job.  The database calls all work fine, and the database is setup properly and working, but when I try to manually test this script from the command line, I get a TypeError.  I am not currently worried if the script is optimal or the function is set up wrong, I am just trying to get it to run from the cmd with no errors.

Here is the script I am running:

```
const inviteRepo = require('../app/repos/invite')

exports.start = function (cb) {
  console.log('beginning function')
  inviteRepo.all((err, myInvites) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return cb(err)
    }
    if (myInvites) {
      let invite
      let n = Date.now()
      let cutoff = 7  // number of days after which invites get deleted
      n += Number(n) - cutoff
      for (invite in myInvites) {
        if (Number(invite.sentAt) < n) {
          inviteRepo.delete(invite._id, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err)
              return cb(err)
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

this.start()  // for testing purposes
```

Here is the function being called with `inviteRepo.all`:

```
exports.all = (cb) => {
  db.invites.find().toArray((err, myInvites) => {
    if (err) return cb(err)
    if (myInvites.length === 0) {
      return cb(null, [])
    } else if (myInvites.length > 0) {
      return cb(null, myInvites)
    }
  })
}
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
db.invites.find().toArray((err, myInvites) => {
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
```

The script is obviously accessing the inviteRepo file just fine, and since the database is required in the inviteRepo file (`const db = require('../../mongodb')`) I don't understand why db.invites is undefined.  Do I need to manually import or require something else in the original script?

Thank you in advance; I'm still getting familiar with node.js and running scripts outside of the normal functioning of the program.

Comment: db.invites.find() works in other contexts of the same program. I tried ```db.collection('invites').find()``` and I got this error: ```db.collection('invites').find().toArray((err, myInvites) => {
     ^

TypeError: db.collection is not a function```

Comment: Silly question: why not use MongoDB's [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) to automatically remove documents after a certain time?

Comment: @kevinadi, I didn't know Mongo had something like that.  It looks like exactly what I need though.  Thanks.